# Dataannotations error in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, data-annotations

I've developed a xamarin.forms app. Everything was working fine and I updated my Visual Studio installation. But now i am getting below errors. Here is the code:

```
 using SQLite;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace SampleApp
    {
       [SQLite.Table("CSV_File")]
public class FileCSV : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }
```

And fere are the errors:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be
>   found     (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error    CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not
>   exist     in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an
>   assembly 
>       reference?)

Comment: have you tried deleting the .vs ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the target profile of your Shared Project to Profile259.